# How to list all outdated packages in a solution?

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget

My goal is to get notified by a build server whenever new packages are available, **but not automatically install them**.

I want to generate a list that shows all the nuget packages used in a solution, that are outdated (a newer version was released but not installed yet).

Is there a way to create that list in a script / powershell?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @sodawillow - What have I tried..? It appears that there is no API for that. I have tried updating everything, and git diff on the package files. But that's quite cumbersome.

Comment: Have you found a way to list all packages used in a solution (outdated or not) ?

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-Package -Updates
```

See the [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#get-package).